# Problema con quick.db | discord.js

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Necesito ayuda y es que todo va bien con mi Bot de Discord, pero el problema es que al reiniciarlo cuando tengo que hacer una actualización a los comandos los cambios en la base de datos no quedan.

Por ejemplo se cambia el prefijo a **p!** y funciona bien, pero al reiniciar el Bot la información no queda almacenada.

Necesito ayuda ya que trabajo en un sistema de economía para este y si no lo soluciono no podre hacerlo

La base de datos es con la librería **quick.db** e intento importarla a **heroku postgres** pero no se como

Comment: No sé si esto cuenta como duplicado porque hay un post idéntico en ingles:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272280/i-use-quick-db-in-my-discord-bot-every-time-i-deploy-an-update-the-db-does-not

Comment: Quick.db guarda sus datos de forma local, en que entorno estas ejecutando tu proyecto?

Comment: En node.js, pero lo subi recientemente a heroku y pues como esta ligado a github los datos se eliminan despues, intente con **heroku postgresql** pero no se como usara, nesesito ayuda con alguna forma de actualizar mi base de datos cuando hayan cambios y que se mantengan ahi despues de reiniciar

Comment: A menos que tengas un plan pago de heroku la unica forma de que no se reinicie tu base de datos por heroku es usar postgresql, en este punto solo te queda aprender a usarlo, aqui tienes un tuto de como hacer uso del servicio de postgres de heroku con nodejs: https://slacker.ro/2020/01/21/adding-a-postgresql-database-to-a-node-js-app-on-heroku/

Comment: @AnkiJedi pero y como hago para importar toda mi base de datos a **postgresql**?, y como hago si tengo la aplicación desde GitHub

Comment: O conoces algun otro lugar donde pueda subir mi apliacion y se actualice automaticamente la base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que Heroku no posee una función para mantener los datos, a exepcion de la libreria **postgresql** se puede intentar otra opción, y es utilizando **repl.it** en el cual los datos quedan almacenados después de un reinicio, la única es subir los archivos directamente, o hacer copia de seguridad cuando se importan desde **GitHub**.

Ademas que es super fácil de utilizar y solo se requiere el paso adicional que es configurarla en **UptimeRobot** para que no se caiga la app y quede 24/7.